# What journals/periodicals are appropriate for serious amateurs to submit findings/research?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, publishing

Are there journals out there that publish work by serious amateurs (but not at the level of academic researcher). I think that MAA journal American Mathematical Monthly is a good example (I could be mistaken).

I have an idea for an article that I think is interesting and potentially useful, but doesn't involve any really crazy advanced theory (e.g., only basic measure theory and calculus of variations with constraints). I would classify my article as probability theory at the advanced undergraduate/early graduate level (in terms of mathematical difficulty).

Comment: In what subject?

Comment: @user170039 see my edits. The article is in probability theory (applied).

Comment: Maybe this is a late comment, did your work get published? If so, can I have a look, just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one called College Mathematics that appears promising.